# people vs episodes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database which has a row per episode with person id, start and end date, a person can have more than one episode and the episodes can overlap. I am trying to use a query to put a flag on only on of the rows for each person, even if all of the rows for that person fit the criteria. Is this possible to do?

So for example Joyce has 5 different episodes between 01/01/18 and 01/04/18, some of which overlap. I am looking for all people who had episodes between 01/02/18 and 01/03/18, this is 3 episodes in the case of Joyce, but I only want to count her once.

I am using queries so no need to declare and set in this instance.

example code

```
     select 
         startdate,
         enddate,
         id,
         case  
            when startdate <= '01/03/18'
            and (enddate is null or enddate >= '01/02/18')
            then 1 else 0 end
     from 
         table
```

this code works, however it picks up every episode and not just each person who has an episode.

example of the table

```
   id   startdate    enddate
   1     01/01/18    31/01/18
   1     01/02/18    22/02/18
   1     12/01/18    25/03/18
   1     20/02/18    29/03/18
```

expected column output

```
     id    startdate    enddate       uniqueflag   
     1     01/01/18    31/01/18          1
     1     01/02/18    22/02/18          0
     1     12/01/18    25/03/18          0
     1     20/02/18    29/03/18          0
```

this is showing that the first row fits the criteria so no need to look at other rows for that id, so move on to the next id. I guess what I want it to do is check the id, then check if the start and end dates are in the criteria, if they are yes then 1 and move onto the next id, if no then 0 and keep checking that id until either one fits the criteria or exhausts all the ID's.

Any help greatly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Also please add some sample source data

Comment: In your code what is the id column?  Is that an episode id or a person id?

Comment: It is a person ID. The table is just a basic table with person id, start date and end date of episode.

Comment: The only reason you don't already have an answer is because this is not very clear what you want here. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: some data and table structure would be great help..

Comment: As I said, it is a simple table. the only columns are ID, startdate and enddate. As I said in the question, each row pertains to one episode.

Comment: Post updated with table example and quotes to please the picky!

Comment: This is clear now, would appreciate if you add expected column output aswel

Comment: Ven I have updated again for you.

Comment: It is not that I don't want to help you. On the contrary I actually do. But I do not want to spend a bunch of my time creating tables and sample data so I can then spend time writing the queries for you. You see, my time here is volunteer work, just like everyone else. And when you don't make it easier for us by putting in the effort for the part that is easy for you to do many of us don't bother. Why should I put in extra effort so you have to do less? That is why I posted the link I did an hour ago. Little things like datatype make a huge difference in things like this.

Comment: Sean, I had already updated my post before you wrote that last comment.

Comment: _this is 3 episodes in the case of Joyce, but I only want to count her once_ To count her only once use `COUNT(DISTINCT Person_Id)` rather than `COUNT(*)`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing single quotes around the date constants. I want to emphasize that you should be using ISO/ANSI standard formats:

```
select startdate, enddate, id,
       (case when startdate <= '2018-01-03' and
                  (enddate is null or enddate >= '2018-01-02')
             then 1 else 0
        end)
from table ;
```

If you only want one row per id, then you want `group by`.  I would guess:

```
select id,
       max(case when startdate <= '2018-01-03' and
                  (enddate is null or enddate >= '2018-01-02')
             then 1 else 0
            end)
from table
group by id;
```

Comment: It is a simple example of code, not an exact replica of my code. I am actually using a function to get the date but that is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: If you want help with code, post that code, exactly. Paraphrasing is unhelpful to those who are spending their free time trying to help you. Especially when you literally wrote _"this code works"_, not "this is pseudocode".

Comment: I cannot give you the code due to data protection, this is why I gave this code. This code does work, it's just a simplified version and it is perfectly fine for the question I am asking. If you don't want to help, then don't!

Comment: Max with group by doesn't work because the dates are all different. I have updated my question so you can see an example of the table.